# Compare to List of objects by one files

Tags: c#, list, compare

I got an entity like

```
 public class MediaObject
 {
       public int ID {get;set;}
       public string Name { get;set;}
       public string FileName {get;set;}
 }
```

How do I get the differences between two lists of MediaObjects comparing by FileName property without iterating

Comment: *"How do i compare two List by the FileName field without iterating"* You can't, no matter if you're writting the loops yourself or use any extensions, there will still be loops under the hood

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Do you want to check if one list contains the same file names as the other? Or something else? Can you give an example input and an expected output?

Comment: if you mean as per `.Except` etc (to get "in x, not in y" deltas) then: LINQ has some methods there, but: it is just *moving* the loop; it still iterates

Comment: I'm confused as to why you would set the constraint of not iterating.

Comment: There was no reason for not iterating just a wish for some simple linq.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if the question was ok but i found the following linq

```
list1.Where(x => !list1.Any(z => x.FileName.ToLower() == z.FileName.ToLower())).ToList();
```